# Thai MVE Visa at Yangon embassy

Tags: visas, thailand, tourist-visas, myanmar

Is it possible to apply for a Thai MEV (Multiple Entry Tourist Visa) at the Thai Embassy in Yangon ?

I can only see the "single entry tourist visa" option on their website.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Thai Embassies are not the best at keeping their websites up to date.  You might need to call to double check as in theory METVs are available to all nationalities.

But METVs are only available in your country of citizenship or legal residence, unlike other Thai visas which can be obtained at various locations.  But TIT, so required proof of residency may vary.

Comment: good point, the embassy replied to my email (see my answer) but it is possible that I get my application rejected for "not residing in Myanmar". Let's see, visas in southeast Asia seems to be very much a "trial and error" process...

Answer (score 1):

I just went to ask for an MEV (Multiple Entry Tourist Visa) for Thailand at their Yangon embassy.

Here is the outcome:

- it is **NOT possible** to get an **MEV (Multiple Entry Tourist Visa)** for Thailand at their Yangon Embassy **if you do not reside in Myanmar**
- <s>however, it is **possible** to get a **3 month Tourist visa** for Thailand at their Yangon embassy, **even if you do not reside in Myanmar**</s> There is no such thing as a 3 months visa. The dates on the visa are giving the timeframe in which you can start using the 2 months tourist visa.

I went on Nov 27th, they took 1 day to process the application. On Nov 28th I had my passport with the <s>3 months</s> 2 months tourist visa. <s>Note that the visa date starts on the actual date of the application, not on the date I enter the country it seems (see the dates on the visa pic).</s> It seems that the dates on the visa is the timeframe you have to enter the country: in this case, you can start using your 2 months tourist visa in the next 3 months.

Triple check your understanding of what visa you get both at **the Thai embassy** where applying for the visa and at **the immigration check** when entering the country. Over staying a visa will earn you a big fine, a lot of time consuming and stressful paperwork.

[image: 2 months Thai tourist visa from the Thai embassy in Yangon]

Comment: I assume you know of the bank account rules, 6000 euro average balance for six months, for an METV?

Comment: @Irked yes I've read that. But criterias seem to be slightly changing depending on where you apply. I will try my best to prepare whatever I can & if it falls through then f*** it